# Parallelizing evaluation and pointwise addition of lists

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have the following code:

```
normalHands :: [[[Char]]]
normalHands = -- a very long list

sevenHeads :: [[[Char]]]
sevenHeads = -- a very long list

countYakus :: [Int]
countYakus = foldr countYaku [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] (normalHands ++ sevenHeads) where
    countYaku hand [p,oP,dT,aS,cS,fS,sO,cF,cT,dM,aO,tOAK,tP,sT,sF,f] =
    -- involves pointwise addition of lists. The length of the accumulator is not changed.
```

How should I parallelize this? I tried the following:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.QSem
import Control.Monad
import Data.List

--...

main :: IO ()
main = let
    [pinfu, onePair, dragonTriplet, allSimples,
        colorfulSequences, fullSequence, semiOrphans, concealedFour, colorfulTriplets, dragonsMinor, allOrphans, threeOfAKind,
        twoPairs, semiTerminals, semiFlush, flush] = countYakus
    in do
        qSem <- newQSem 0
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("0: " ++ show pinfu ++ ' ' : show onePair) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("1: " ++ show dragonTriplet ++ ' ' : show allSimples) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("2: " ++ show colorfulSequences ++ ' ' : show fullSequence) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("3: " ++ show semiOrphans ++ ' ' : show concealedFour) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("4: " ++ show colorfulTriplets ++ ' ' : show dragonsMinor) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("5: " ++ show allOrphans ++ ' ' : show threeOfAKind) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("6: " ++ show twoPairs ++ ' ' : show semiTerminals) >> signalQSem qSem
        forkIO $ putStrLn ("7: " ++ show semiFlush ++ ' ' : show flush) >> signalQSem qSem
        sequence_ $ replicate 8 (waitQSem qSem)
```

I compiled this with `-O2 +RTS -N8`, but despite I have 8 cores, my system monitor clearly shows that this code is being run in only one core. I guess it's because of `normalHands ++ sevenHeads`. So what is the correct way to parallelize this?

**EDIT:** Exploiting the associativity and commutativity of pointwise addition, I tried this:

```
countYakus :: [[[Char]]] -> [Int]
countYakus = foldl' countYaku [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] where
    -- ...


divideList :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
divideList 0 _ = []
divideList n xs = let
    (ys,zs) = splitAt n xs
    in if null zs
        then coZip ys (replicate n [])
        else coZip ys (divideList n zs)
  where
    coZip :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
    coZip [] yss = yss
    coZip (x:xs) (ys:yss) = (x:ys) : coZip xs yss

main :: IO ()
main = do
    acc <- newIORef [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    mapM_ (\hands -> forkIO . atomicModifyIORef' acc $ \cs -> (zipWith (+) cs $ countYakus hands, ())) $ divideList 8 (normalHands ++ sevenHeads)
    cs <- readIORef acc
    mapM_ (putStrLn . show) cs
```

But it still runs only on one core.

**EDIT 2:** I tried using MVar:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    acc <- newIORef [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    mVar <- newEmptyMVar
    mapM_ (\hands -> forkIO $ putMVar mVar (countYakus hands)) $ divideList 8 (normalHands ++ sevenHeads)
    replicateM_ 8 $ do
        xs <- takeMVar mVar
        ys <- readIORef acc
        writeIORef acc (zipWith (+) xs ys)
    cs <- readIORef acc
    mapM_ (putStrLn . show) cs
```

But it still runs on only one core.

Comment: You can't parallelize a `foldr`, in the general case. If your specific case, the operation is pointwise addition, which is associative, so there is hope -- some library might provide a parallel fold for associative operations. I'd look on hoogle to see if something like that exists.

Comment: Here is a prallell right fold for you on arrays, instead of lists: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2020-02-17/massiv-0.5.0.0/Data-Massiv-Array.html#v:ifoldrP

Comment: @chi actually you _can_ parallelise it, if the function you fold over factors into a substantial “pre-processing” part and a simpler combining-part. (So that basically the expensive part of the task could also be written with `map`.) But here, there doesn't seem to be any computation-heavy part at all, and the entire thing will thus likely be throttled by cache mismatches due to the non-compact list in memory.

Comment: @lehins Regarding the unknown yet emornous length of `normalHands ++ sevenHeads`, I don't think an array would help.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The most computation-heavy part is `countYaku`. It involves mass pattern matching.

Comment: @DannyuNDos its always possible to use an array, even if you have to use many chunks of arrays. Regardless of that point, look into https://github.com/lehins/haskell-scheduler I think you'll find it much easier to implement parallelization of fold (since that's what is being used for massiv) for lists then reinventing the wheel yourself. There are already example in the library how to do traverse, shouldn't be to hard to expand to a list.

Comment: Alternatively you can also try https://www.stackage.org/package/streamly from what I hear it is also capable of processing streams in parallel. Lists are inherently very inefficient data structures, unless they fuse you will pay significant price.